# How to set new row with logo in bootstrap login form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build my login page with Bootstrap 3 and still I'm in the process of learning all the classes. Here is example of my login page:

```css
.form-login{
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-login .form-login-heading, .form-login{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-login .form-control{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-login .form-control:focus{
    z-index: 2;
}
.account-wall{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.page-title{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}
.login-title{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}
.security-logo {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>My Application Login Page</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="JS/Login.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Login.css"> 
    </head>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="account-wall">
              <h1 class="text-center page-title">My Application</h1>
              <form name="ha_login" id="ha_login" class="form-login">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" maxlength="25" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" maxlength="12" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
                <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <a href="#" class="pull-left">Forgot Password</a>
                  <a href="#" class="pull-right">Need help?</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="pull-right security-logo">Logo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

In my snippet you can see that Logo in in the middle of the row. I would like my Logo to be aligned to the right side. I'm not sure If I can use another row with the same cell classes since their is different number of elements. If anyone can provide any help please let me know.

Comment: *"I would like my Logo to be aligned to the right side"* -- to the right side of what??

Comment: @WebDevBooster to the right side of the screen. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4? The code snippet shows Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @ZimSystem I couldn't find the tag for Bootstrap 3...

Comment: The whole thing centered but the logo aligned to the right side of the screen??

Comment: @WebDevBooster I see your update and I'm confused why tag is set to twitter-bootstrap. If you run the snippet and click full screen you will see that logo is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Because that's the tag for Bootstrap 3. (I'd also rather have SO update that old name to the appropriate current name, but they don't)

Comment: If you add this style rule to your css, it'll push your logo to the right with a little margin on the right: .account-wall h1{ float: right; margin-right: 25px; }
I don't think your issue is bootstrap related.